# ifstream won't find file even though it's in the same directory

Tags: c++, file, ifstream

I've got a method to read a vector of bools from a file:

```cpp
std::vector<bool> OPCConnector::getAlarmVector() {
    std::vector<bool> data;
    std::ifstream DataFile(filepath);

    if (DataFile) {
        bool value;

        while (DataFile >> value) {
            data.push_back(value);
            std::cout << value;
        }
    }
    
    return data;
}
```

The `filepath` variable is an object property that is assigned through the constructor:

```
OPCConnector::OPCConnector(std::string fpth) {
    filepath = fpth;
}
```

And in the `main()` function, the constructor is called:

```cpp
std::vector<bool> activations;
std::string filepath = "alarmes.txt";
OPCConnector opcc = OPCConnector(filepath);
activations = opcc.getAlarmVector();
```

Now, I've checked what the folder of the executable is via [`GetModuleFileNameA()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamea), and I made sure that the file is in the same directory and has the same name (also, I made sure that the extension isn't part of the file name, like `"alarmes.txt.txt"`).

I debugged the first method `getAlarmVector()` and it never gets past the `if (DataFile)` condition, as if it won't find file.

I run the code using Visual Studio 2019, and nothing happens. The vector remains empty. Error is **No such file or directory.**

[image: Project dir settings]

Default working directory is `$(ProjectDir)` and it's exactly where my file is.

**Edit:** I've also tried using both relative and absolute paths, none work.

**Edit 2:** I've also checked the directory using [`GetCurrentDirectory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory) and copied the `.txt` file there too, and it isn't working.

**SOLUTION:** Strangely enough, I deleted the file and created it again with the same name, and it worked. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Check [`GetCurrentDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory)

Comment: With VS, you need to put the files in the same location where the source files are.  For example, if your project is named CoolCode.  You should have a path like `SOMEDRIVE:path_to_projectfiles/CoolCode/CoolCode/` and in there, there will be your source files and a debug and release folders.  Put your text file there and see if it opens.

Comment: `else { std::perror("OpenDataFile"); }` and in `stderr` you will know what is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. Just in case, I copied the file there too, and in several other folders. None seem to work. Posting an edit,

Comment: Ok `No such file or directory` means that path is invalid or current directory is different then you assumed. I'm guessing Jeseph Lastson is right.

Comment: You could change your code to create a file for writing instead and see where it ends up.

Comment: Next time `(i|o)fstream` fails to open a file, consider using `CreateFile(A|W)` instead so you can check its error code for why it failed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Windows API is not needed. Just `errno` and `std::strerror` or `std::perror` are just fine and work on all platforms.

Answer (score 6):

My guess: your current working directory isn't what you think it is, especially if you're running from an IDE. I know of several IDEs where the current working directory is some build directory (it varies by IDE) unless you specifically change it.

I'm fairly sure Visual Studio is one such IDE.

---

Here's a tiny example program I wrote;

```
$ cat Foo.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int, char **) {
    std::ifstream file { "Foo.cpp" };

    if (file) {
        std::cout << "File opened.\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "File not opened.\n";
    }
}
```

Compile and run it:

```
$ g++ --std=c++17 Foo.cpp -o Foo && Foo
File opened.
```

Comment: VS usually uses `Debug`, `Release` or `x64/Debug`, `x64/Release` directories relative to project directory by default.

Comment: And where can I check what my directory is? I've tried using an absolute path specifying C:\\... I've tried using GetCurrentDirectory and copied the file there too...

Comment: Have you tried writing a very simple program that reads a file? I don't see anything specifically wrong in your code. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: Wrote a couple lines to create a .txt file and see where it was created and it was in the same directory I had the file. I fixed it, I still don't know how. Positing it in the question. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1):

Current folder and folder-of-exe-file are different things (sometimes). Try to specify full name of file (with disk, all folders, etc.).

You can check errors of file open operation by calling

```
if (!DataFile) { ... }
```

Comment: He checks for error, but doesn't do anything meaningful in error branch.  Your answer doesn't do anything meaningful in error branch too.

Answer (score 1):

The `std::filesystem` library can help you resolve file and path related issues.

```
#include <filesystem>


    // (in some function)
    std::filesystem::path filepath = "alarmes.txt";
    if ( !exists(filepath) )
    {
        std::cout << "File path " << filepath << " at absolute location "
                  << absolute(filepath) << " does not exist\n";
    }
```

[See it on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/aP6zaj4Y6)

Answer (score 0):

You can get an error code (and get a description of error in internet) if you use C-function `fopen`. If open is failed, you get the nullptr as result of fopen and `errno` will contain code of error.